# Spark DataFrame: Is order of withColumn guaranteed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Given the following code:

```
dataFrame
    .withColumn("A", myUdf1($"x")) // withColumn1 from x
    .withColumn("B", myUdf2($"y")) // withColumn2 from y
```

Is it guaranteed that `withColumn1` will execute before `withColumn2`?

A better example:

```
dataFrame
    .withColumn("A", myUdf1($"x")) // withColumn1 from x
    .withColumn("B", myUdf2($"A")) // withColumn2 from A!!
```

Note that withColumn2 operates on `A` that is calculated from `withColumn1`.

I'm asking because I'm having inconsistent results over multiple runs of the same code and I started to think that this could be the source of the issue.

**EDIT: Added more detailed code sample**

```
val result = dataFrame
  .groupBy("key")
  .agg(
    collect_list($"itemList").as("A"),                          // all items
    collect_list(when($"click".isNotNull, $"itemList")).as("B") // subset of A
  )
  // create sparse item vector from all list of items A
  .withColumn("vectorA", aggToSparseUdf($"A"))                  
  // create sparse item vector from all list of items B (subset of A)
  .withColumn("vectorB", aggToSparseUdf($"B"))      
  // calculate ratio vector B / A
  .withColumn("ratio", divideVectors($"vectorB", $"vectorA"))

val keys: Seq[String] = result.head.getAs[Seq[String]]("key")
val values: Seq[SparseVector] = result.head.getAs[Seq[SparseVector]]("ratio")
```

Comment: One reason is that I want to take a look at both A and B. Also, in certain cases, the code is more readable. Finally, myUdf2 performs all operations of myUdf1 + others and I want to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It **IS** guaranteed that for each *specific record* in `dataFrame`, `myUdf1` will be applied before `myUdf2`; However:
2. It is **NOT** guaranteed that `myUdf1` will be applied to *all records* of `dataFrame` before `myUdf2` is applied to *any record* - in other words, `myUdf2` might be applied to some records before `myUdf1` has been applied to *other* records

This is true because Spark would likely combine both operations together into a single *stage*, and execute this stage (applying `myUdf1` and `myUdf2`) on each record of each partition.

This shouldn't pose any problem if your UDFs are "**purely functional**", or "idempotent", or cause no side effects - and they *should* be, because Spark assumes all *transformations* are such. If they weren't, Spark wouldn't be able to optimize execution by "combining" transformations together, running them in parallel on different partitions, retrying transformations etc.

**EDIT**: if you want to *force* UDF1 to be completely applied before applying UDF2 to any record, you'd have to force them into **separate stages** - this can be done, for example, by *repartitioning* the DataFrame:

```
// sample data:
val dataFrame = Seq("A", "V", "D").toDF("x")

// two UDFs with "side effects" (printing to console):
val myUdf1 = udf[String, String](x => {
  println("In UDF1")
  x.toLowerCase
})

val myUdf2 = udf[String, String](x => {
  println("In UDF2")
  x.toUpperCase
})

// repartitioning between UDFs
dataFrame
  .withColumn("A", myUdf1($"x"))
  .repartition(dataFrame.rdd.partitions.length + 1)
  .withColumn("B", myUdf2($"A"))
  .show()

// prints:
// In UDF1
// In UDF1
// In UDF1
// In UDF2
// In UDF2
// In UDF2
```

**NOTE** that this isn't bullet-proof either - if, for example, there are failures and retries, order can be once again non deterministic.

Comment: will try the repartition to see if I have consistent results. Would persist/cache work as a "checkpoint". In Scalding I was sometimes using `.forceToDisk` to achieve a similar thing

Comment: Actually, yes - `cache()` / `persist()` should work too.

Comment: I added a more specific example. Hopefully, you can determine if the issue depends on the code. Feel free to propose alternative/simpler implementations

Comment: cache() is not guaranteed though, it's just a hint to Spark, right?